# knockoutjs in express using ejs

Tags: node.js, knockout.js, ejs

I would like to start using knockoutjs in a web app currently based on Nodejs with express using ejs view engine.

index.ejs

```
<% layout('layout') -%>
  <!-- Jquery Include-->
  <script src="/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Knockout Javascript Dependency-->
  <script src="/js/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var viewModel = {
        firstName : "Bert"
      };
      ko.applyBindings(viewModel);   
  </script>

  <p>First Name: <span data-bind="text: firstName"></span></p>
```

It appears that knockout js is loading properly  however, the data-binding is not working I simply see.

First Name:

Is there a compatibility issue loading knockout in an ejs file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no compatibility issues with ejs - as far as I know - however you need to call `ko.applyBindings` after your DOM is loaded, from the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html):

> To activate Knockout, add the following line to a  block:
>
> `ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);`
>
> You can either put the script block at the bottom of your HTML
>   document, or you can put it at the top and wrap the contents in a
>   DOM-ready handler such as jQuery’s $ function.

So you need to change your template to move the `ko.applyBindings` at the end:

```
<% layout('layout') -%>
  <!-- Jquery Include-->
  <script src="/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Knockout Javascript Dependency-->
  <script src="/js/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>

  <p>First Name: <span data-bind="text: firstName"></span></p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      var viewModel = {
        firstName = "Bert"
      };
      ko.applyBindings(viewModel);   
  </script>
```

Or use the jQuery’s `$` function:

```
<% layout('layout') -%>
  <!-- Jquery Include-->
  <script src="/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Knockout Javascript Dependency-->
  <script src="/js/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var viewModel = {
        firstName = "Bert"
      };
      $(function() {
          ko.applyBindings(viewModel);  
      }); 
  </script>

  <p>First Name: <span data-bind="text: firstName"></span></p>
```